# How to return ID from onClick in a function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have template setup in a function, and i want it to pass its ID when it's clicked - but somehow the way i have set it up now, it gets clicked as the element is loaded, and i am unable to click it afterwards.

```
import React from 'react'

function PortItem(props){
    return(
        <div className="portItem" onClick={props.click(props.pitem.id)}>
            <img src={props.pitem.src} alt={props.pitem.title}></img>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PortItem
```

The Console.log logs the correct ID, but does it immediately as the element is loaded.

```
import React from 'react'
import portData from "./portData"
import PortItem from "./portItem"

function PortfolioPage() {
    const handleClick = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
    }

    const portItems = portData.map(item => <PortItem key={item.id} pitem={item} click={handleClick}/>)

    return (
        <div>
            {portItems} 
        </div>
    )
}

export default PortfolioPage
```

How do i make it behave as you would expect it to? So that when the div with the className "portItem" is clicked, it passes its ID to the handleClick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
<div className="portItem" onClick={()=>props.click(props.pitem.id)}>
```

This makes sure that only when we click on the `div` the handler function is invoked and also the value is passed to the handler.

This is a general way to pass the values to handlers, where we basically use a function within a `Synthetic Event` (in your case `onClick`)

```
onEvent={()=>{handlerFunction(value)}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling it every time the element renders. You should change it to:

```
<div className="portItem" onClick={() => props.click(props.pitem.id)}>
```